# Find which button is clicked

Tags: silverlight, buttonclick, windows-phone-7.1.1

In my windows phone application, I have a LoadMore button in one page. The loadmore button is defined in `style` in  `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>` section. I have 2 listboxes in that page and uses the same style for both of the listboxes. When I click on the loadmore button, how can I identify the LoadMore button in which listbox raise the event?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    <Button Content="Load More..." Name="btnLoadMore" Visibility="Visible" Background="White" Foreground="#FF176DDC" Click="btnLoadMore_Click"></Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

How can I find the button in which listbox is clicked?

Comment: You should probably check out the `sender` parameter in you `btnLoadMore_Click` event handler. Cast it back to a button and check out it's name. There will probably be some kind of suffix added to the name, because there can't be double names.

Comment: @Gerald Versluis :I tried it but no use. Every time I got the same name. ie btnLoadMore. Then I remove the button name and tried, I got no name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have that kind of functionality in a style in my opinion is the wrong approach. Try putting the `ListBox` and the `Button` into a `UserControl`, that itself exposes an event for loading more data.
Internally you then handle the `Click`-event of the button and raise the `UserControl`'s `LoadMore`-event.